# Filtrar dbgrid com campos lookup

Tags: mysql, delphi, filter, dbgrid

Fiz um form genérico de pesquisa para a minha aplicação, mas agora percebi que não posso filtrar o dataset utilizando campos lookup, existe uma alternativa para não utilizar uma query? Um componente que consiga fazer isso livre ou comercial? Abaixo a procedure que utilizo junto ao um combobox e um edit.

```
procedure Pesquisa(DS : TDataSource; Field : string; Value : string);
begin
  DS.DataSet.Filter := 'Upper(' + Field + ') like ' + QuotedStr('%' + UpperCase(Value) + '%');
  DS.DataSet.Filtered := True;
end;
```

Comment: Os componentes da DevExpress fazem isso muito facilmente. Mas acredito que não seja viável adquiri-los apenas por essa funcionalidade. Nunca precisei implementar isso, mas vamos ver se alguém aparece com uma alternativa mais viável.

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade realmente comprar DevExpress não da pra mim, tinha que ser muito barato. Vou utilizando um query por enquanto, como o form é gerico não vai dar trabalho mudar. Vlw.

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade mas no caso o DevExpress tem um componente Grid que permite isso?

Comment: @user21051, de uma olhada neste artigo que talvez possa te ajudar: http://ainfo.cnptia.embrapa.br/digital/bitstream/CPPSE/15593/1/PROCIRFS2005.0004.PDF
Ele fala em usar um evento OnfilterRecord para fazer isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defina `DataSet.Filtered := True` e adicione o seguinte código ao OnFilterRecord do seu DataSet:

```
procedure TForm1.DataSetFilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := AnsiContainsText(DataSet.FieldByName(Field).AsString, Value);
end;
```

Field e Value devem ser variáveis no seu form que são definidas pelo seu botão de pesquisa (juntamente com `Filtered = True`).

Adicione também `StrUtils` ao `uses` para poder usar a função `AnsiContainsText`.

PS: A menos que sua aplicação seja local, com um BD pequeno, você não deve usar isso. Eu, pelo hábito, não usaria nem nesse caso. Faria uma query dinâmica mesmo. Esse filtro opera localmente (assim como a propriedade `Filter`) e se você estiver em uma rede, isso significa que você está trafegando a tabela inteira para depois filtrar localmente (e com certeza sem índices, otimizações e o poder computacional do servidor). Na minha experiencia, o maior gargalo de performance está no tráfego de rede, então isso tem o potencial enorme para fazer uma aplicação MUITO lenta.

Comment: é uma aplicação em 3 camadas Datasnap caro @GabrielF. Neste caso vc indica eu fazer uma query mesmo e nunca trazer todos os dados para depois filtrar?